# implementing socket.io on NextJS 13 with App directory

Tags: next.js, socket.io, next.js13

How can initialize socket with App directory in `app/api/socket/route.js` ?

It doesnt return instance of `http.ServerResponse` like example below in `pages/api/socket.js` directory. It returns `NextResponse` which doesnt have socket property to create an io instance with.

```
import { Server } from "socket.io";

export default function SocketHandler(req, res) {
  if (res.socket.server.io) {
    console.log("Socket is already running");
  } else {
    console.log("Socket is initializing");
    const io = new Server(res.socket.server);
    res.socket.server.io = io;

    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
      console.log("client connected", socket.id);
    });
  }
  res.end();
}
```

Comment: some issues [49334](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/49334) [48422](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/48422) have been created on gihub

Comment: have you use headers ? check this: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/headers

Comment: Have anyone solved that? I'm using NextJS App and can't get it working...

Comment: Subscribing. I have been using the OP method reliably but we will need a migration path eventually. Has anyone here submitted a discussion on github?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that after "13.2.5-canary.26", a trailing slash is appended to the end of the route.

Disabling "addTrailingSlash" in the Socket.IO Server constructor resolves this issue.

"pages/api/socket.js"

```
const io = new Server(res.socket.server, {
  path: '/api/socket_io',
  addTrailingSlash: false,
});
```

in page.jsx :

```
const socket = io(undefined, {
  path: '/api/socket_io',
});
```

More info can be found here:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/49334#issuecomment-1539867051

Comment: at the time I answered this question /api folder was only working on pages/api

Comment: yeah I forgot that we have two routing in nextjs...

Answer (score 1):

If you were having issues previously, next.js version `13.5` now fixes the issue that socket.io wasn't working since version [13.3.5-canary.27](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/49334) but it is working now on `13.5.2`

Comment: If you look at the bottom of the thread you linked to you’ll see that it’s still an issue. Can you confirm that you have it working with 13.5.x?

Comment: @bfeist Looks like it isn't working still.

Comment: @aetheros It only works if it's pages/api/*, it won't works if it's in the new app/api/* router

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with that.
I think you can't use webSockets in **app directory**, you should make a separate server for handling sockets
Or use the pages for that,
but there is a problem after version 13.2.5 at next.js that socket server doesn't work in it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I am also facing the same issue with app router in nextjs 13. It's better if you use a dedicated server for chat purpose individually or switch to page directory structure which is still supported by next versions.